# PDF attached with Paperclip - get document properties (like page count)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, pdf.js

In my app to learn RoR, I want to see how to handle attachments. Got paperclip to work and want to get document properties. So, how can I get document properties (PDF info) from pdf files (attached using Paperclip)?

One way is to use command line, yet how to get it the file (here `@annotation.file` - or for other object `@document.file`)? Actually, I would need to download the file to a temp folder to do this and do a file delete to clean up. How can I get the details without download?

So controller to look like this:

```
def pdf
    @annotation = Annotation.find(params[:id])
    render layout: false
    command = 'pdfinfo @annotation.file'
    no_of_pages = command.split("\n")[-7].split(":").last.strip
end
```

It throws an error:

> undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass

I get it to my annotation view using:

```
<%= @no_of_pages %>
```

Meanwhile I looked at the gem "`[pdfinfo][1]`" as an alternative, yet how to use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy solutionL use the PDFINFO gem; works very well

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using a `gem`, you can also fetch the details of any `pdf` using linux's in-built commands. Just write the below ruby code for executing and you will get all the details. For ex:

For executing a `linux` command in your ruby code, write that command like :

```
def pdf
    @annotation = Annotation.find(params[:id])
    command = `pdfinfo @annotation.file`
    @no_of_pages = command.split("\n")[-7].split(":").last.strip
    render layout: false
end
```

you will get all the details like no. of pages, file_size etc in your `command` variable.
You can easily fetch the respective details you want. 
I hope this helped !!

> UPDATE

Note : give a proper path for your pdf file, the exact directory where it is placed. like in my case :

```
command = `pdfinfo /home/hbiyawarwala/Documents/books/Rails-Angular-Postgres-and-Bootstrap.pdf`
```

Second thing is, use variable `@no_of_pages` directly in your view like

```
<%= @no_of_pages %>
```

Comment: so in erb I would make that '<%= cmd = 'pdfinfo @annotation.file' %>' ? (here 'annotation.file' is the respective file)

Comment: @DimitrideRuiter : No in your controller's action, write the code given in the answer, the fetched results will contain all the data about that particular `pdf`. apply the neccessary logic for fetching your info from that data and then just use it your `view`.

Comment: totally new to ruby and rails - ok will update question with controller. Now how would I get the different data then from pdfinfo?

Comment: Thanks, that really helps. Where could i find more details on pdfinfo to know how to strip like you did?

Comment: @DimitrideRuiter : Happy to help :). i would be more if you can upvote my answer ;)

Comment: @DimitrideRuiter : `strip` is ruby's method used for manipulating strings. And pdfinfo is linux's in-built command for pdf doing operations.

Comment: yes but how to know what to strip for size or create date etc.?

Comment: @DimitrideRuiter : I have updated my answer regarding the error you were getting. please do the necessary changes.

Comment: my file is an attachment (I use paperclip gem for that) - so I use '@annotation.file'. Still throws the error on the split method. Also when I use '@annotation.file.url'.

See you are reading Dave Copeland's book too ;-)

Comment: @DimitrideRuiter : you can download your file and then you can give the specific directory in which that file is saved. The given code will work fine. and yes but haven't completed ;)

Comment: if i download, i need to clean up too. How could it be done without download?

Comment: huzefa - could you help me further pls? I have found the pdfinfo gem to provide most details, yet I need to download it too and no clue how (incl the clean up afterward.